# Performace improvement of a Resque Job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

I am building a resque job that will perform very heavy calculations on a large array(over 70K elements).

Basically each element of an array is an argument to the function that performs the heavy calculations. The function is written in a separate File in the `lib` folder. The process is very slow as of now running only on 1 thread at a time instead of 4 or 5.

I tried something like this:

```
thread = []
new_array = original_array.each_slice(original_array.length/4).to_a #Split array in 4 parts so we can have a thread for each part
new_array.each do |a|
  thread << Thread.new {
    a.each do |element|
      establish_active_record_connection do |conn|
        perform_heavy_operation(element)
      end
    end
  }
end
thread.each {|t| t.join}
......
```

but it did not run 4 concurrent threads to speed up the process. After that I tried `fork` instead of thread. Not enough improvement.

Anyone has dealt with concurrent threads in ruby extensively that has any suggestions on how to improve such implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is possible because it depends of your implementation, but you could try to run it in batches. Accept batches of 5k elements for example and try playing around.

Comment: Also figure out what your bottleneck is - if it is database io then adding concurency could degrade performance.

Comment: I am trying to figure out now what the bottleneck is. I believe the computations are really heavy, and a cluster would probably be better, but will try to optimize the queries the max I can.